# How can I replace a parameter by name using a decorator?

Tags: python, python-decorators

How can I create a decorator that replaces the value of a parameter passed to the decorated function?

```
from functools import wraps

def transform_param(param_to_transform):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def with_transform_param(*args, **kwargs):
            import inspect

            signature = inspect.siganture(func)

            # if param_to_transform in signature
            # transform that parameter in some way
            # and pass to func

            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return with_transform_param

    return decorator
```

I'm trying to create a decorator to automatically decrypt a parameter passed to a function, so that the decorated function is separated from the concerns of the decryption.

For the inner part, the best I could think of was:

```
if parameter == param_to_transform:
    args = (
        args[:index]
        + (transform(args[index]),)
        + args[index+1:]
    )
```

But this breaks with kwargs.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need. How do you want to be able to use that decorator?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a decorator is nice, but since this would theoretically apply all the time to named parameters of any old function, you could achieve the same thing more simply.

```
def some_function(a=3, b=4):
    return a + b

def my_transform(**kwargs):
    # Pretend the decryption transform is just subtracting 10.
    return {k: v - 10 for k, v in kwargs.items()}

def decrypt_apply(transform, f, *args, **kwargs):
    return f(*args, **transform(**kwargs))
```

For example:

```
In [30]: decrypt_apply(my_transform, some_function, a=24, b=38)
Out[30]: 42
```

This is analogously easy to compose over the transform function and the base function, especially e.g. using `functools.partial`, and it doesn't involve needing to introspect the argument signature or involve the misdirection of a decorator.

The other nice thing is that if you pass incorrectly named keyword arguments into the `decrypt_apply` function, it will happily try to pass them to the transformer and the base function, which results in nice errors that indicate calling with unsupported arguments, rather than possibly silently allowing this in the body of the decorator.

If you want to extend it to transform either position or keyword arguments, just pass in two different transform functions (each of which could further just be making a call to other transform functions to allow lots of code re-use).

For example:

```
def some_function(a, b=3, c=4):
    return a + b + c

def my_logic(value):
    # Pretend the decryption transform is just subtracting 10.
    return value - 10

def arg_transform(logic, *args):
    return tuple(logic(arg) for arg in args)

def kwarg_transform(logic, **kwargs):
    return {k: logic(v) for k, v in kwargs.items()}

def decrypt_apply(logic, f, *args, **kwargs):
    # This function could parameterize `logic` as I did here,
    # or it could directly parameterize `arg_transform` and
    # `kwarg_transform`, just depends on which better factors
    # your specific business logic. 
    return f(*arg_transform(logic, *args), **kwarg_transform(logic, **kwargs))
```

E.g.:

```
In [37]: decrypt_apply(my_logic, some_function, 24, b=10, c=38)
Out[37]: 42
```

Obviously, you could make the `logic` argument to `arg_transform` or `kwarg_transform` as complicated as you like, checking for specific variable names, applying different transformations based on different positions of the input, etc.

It can quickly become a big mess though, which is why it's often better not to try for a bunch of tricky metaprogramming and literally just write a simple helper module that directly provides transforms for exactly the cases you actually have... and don't worry about expanding it to handle more generic cases or more generic concepts of argument-specific transformer logic until you literally cannot do it via mere addition of helper functions any longer.

I think the moral of the story is that for simple case, decorators are nothing more than first-class function handlers. But since Python offers first-class functions directly, you can just write functions that manipulate other functions.

The benefit of organizing it as a decorator, IMO, comes when the decorated logic is more complicated and is not a simple transformation of arguments, or when there is some other constraint that causes the decorator to be friendlier, like for an API.

Comment: Yeah - my intended solution would also break if it accepted a kwarg or arg using *args or **kwargs which is kind of a problem as well. +1 on the avoiding tricky metaprogramming.